# Как сделать элементы по центру в контейнере div

Tags: html, css

Вот мне говорили что нужно `justify-content: center;` но тут это не работает - почему?
[image: как есть]

Хочу чтобы эти 2 элемента (видео и форма) были по центру в div.main_content

(если нужно прикреплю код - пишите)

Comment: Скорее всего из-за того, что блоки внутри заняли все 80% флексового родителя. Попробуйте `margin: 0 auto`.

Comment: да `margin:auto` помог
@OliverPatterson спасибо тебе большое что отвечаешь на вопросы

Comment: Можете написать в [телеграм](https://t.me/CzarOfScripts) и спрашивать там ‍♂️

Comment: Попробуйте `text-align: center;` И прикрепите, пожалуйста, ваш код...

Comment: Margin: 0px auto

Comment: @Alexey тут `text-align:center` не причём - вопрос в том как 2 дива по центру сделать - а не в том как выровнять текст по центру (горизонтали)
На счёт кода да я сейчас то что у меня получилось прикреплю чтобы другой человек понял

Answer (score 0):

`margin:0 auto` помогло
Автор ответа:@Oliver Patterson

```css
body {
    background-color: #151515;
}

.main_content {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    width: 80%;
    height:60%;
    grid-gap: 5%;
    margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">

<div class="content">
    <div class="main_content">

        <div class="video">
            <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/waFZHI36YVU" title="YouTube video player" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture; web-share" allowfullscreen></iframe>
        </div>

        <div class="form">
            <h2>Enter your email</h2>
            <input type="text" placeholder="Enter your name">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Enter your email">
            <a href="#">Get instruction</a>
        </div>
</div>
```